# No space between circle and left line

Tags: css

I would like to put a circle in middle of my page with line before and after.

I've done something like that but I don't know why there is a space between circle and right line.
There is no space between circle and left line, someone know why?

```
<p class="circle">●</p>

.circle{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #4D9EBD;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.circle:before{
  content: '---------';
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  color: grey;

}
.circle:after{
  content: '---------';
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  color: grey;
}
```

Comment: A partial explanation is that the `letter-spacing` property works only inside the thing you apply it to; so it does nothing between the circle and the minuses. If you give the entire `p` a letter-spacing, you will see that the before and after pseudo elements are affected too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is caused by the letter spacing, which makes your before and after content go outside the box. I usually use a flex solution for things like these.
https://jsfiddle.net/0zoyodzj/

```
.circle {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  color: #4D9EBD;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.circle:before,
.circle:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: grey;
  height: 3px;
  width: 4rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add property margin-left. You can edit your CSS block with below code:

```
.circle:after {
    content: '---------';
    letter-spacing: -10px;
    color: grey;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very muche for help !

Comment: If you get your answer, mark the answer correct and also up vote if you want. :)

Comment: But this doesn't address the question why it happens to the right and not to the left. I would find such an answer much more interesting than this simple hack.

Comment: I have given solution he wants for the question. Explanation might not have helped him to get that solved as he is beginner in the CSS. Just wanted to help him to get it solved!

Comment: I'm also more interested in why it happens

Comment: Sure let me explain that too! When we apply CSS to The :before and :after pseudo-elements elements, it is applied to those elements only not the main element. And every element is having by default letter spacing between characters. But when we reduce the spacing, it is applied to that particular element only.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="circle">●</p>

.circle{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #4D9EBD;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  margin-right: 10px;

}

.circle:before{
  content: '---------';
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  color: grey;

}
.circle:after{
  content: '---------';
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  color: grey;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Use margin-left in `.circle:after` or `margin-right: 10px;` in `.circle`